# Should I use Signals for any variable I want to display in my Angular 17+ component?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection, angular-signals

With the addition of Signals and the way they improve Change Detection, I'm wondering if I should start using Signals only (instead of class variables) in order to display data in my component template to improve performance?

Update data in your template using a variable:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-foo',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [CommonModule],
    template: `<div>Message from the component: {{ message }}</div>`,
})
export class TwoComponent {
    public message = 'Hello World!';

    // Random way to update the message and automatically trigger Change Detection
    public changeMessage(value: string): void {
        this.message = value;
    }
}
```

VS update data in your template using a Signal:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, signal } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-foo',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [CommonModule],
    template: `<div>Message from the component: {{ message() }}</div>`,
})
export class FooComponent {
    public message = signal('Hello World!');

    // Random way to update the message signal and automatically trigger Change Detection
    public changeMessage(value: string): void {
        this.message.set(value);
    }
}
```

*In this example I have a very basic template and a string, of course the Change Detection impact could be bigger for complex objects, arrays or complex views. Also, in many situations the Signal might exist in your Service/Store layer.*

**UPDATE**
It is to my understanding that if you use Signals only, Change Detection can be configured as `OnPush`, which might also improve the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples, the code of the `changeMessage()` method will not schedule a Change Detection cycle.

Currently, Angular uses ZoneJS to schedule Change Detection (CD) cycles. ZoneJS monkey-patches async DOM APIs and most of the DOM events.

To call `changeMessage()`, you'll add some `click` event handler or some `setTimeout()` call - only because DOM events and async APIs are patched (and watched) by ZoneJS, Angular will know that it's time to run a CD cycle.

So it's not `changeMessage()` triggering Change Detection, but the event you generate to call `changeMessage()`. You can [read more about Angular Change Detection here](https://medium.com/@eugeniyoz/angular-change-detection-today-and-tomorrow-b9c64bd294f8).

The Angular team has plans to improve this situation, and components with the `OnPush` strategy will not need ZoneJS (and it will significantly improve performance).

The best things you can do right now for performance:

- Use the `OnPush` strategy in new components;
- Use Signals for variables in templates of new components.

`OnPush` can be used either with Signals or with Observables + `async` pipe.